# Creating a view causes Cassandra Mutation messages to drop

Tags: cassandra, database-administration, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra 3.0.9 cluster with 9 nodes and a replication factor of 3.  When I try and make a materialized view almost immediately I see a large number of dropped mutation messages, but only on two nodes.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: are there GCs or high load from trying to build the view?

Comment: There's no read/write load going on and GC is around 150ms.  We also have a heap of 22GB if that matters.
GC tuning settings are:

-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16
-XX:ConcGCThreads=16
-XX:G1ReservePercent=25

Comment: You would probably need to share your logs for a better diagnosis, but there's been a number of jiras and fixes in MVs since 3.0.9, if you can upgrade to the latest release on this stream you might find an improvement.

Comment: @markc Yup, I wasn't sure which logs I would need to post.  Will try upgrading Cassandra and see if that helps.

Comment: @NickCollins - so the logs are normally under `/var/log/cassandra` the `system.log` and `debug.log` are useful here. Look for obvious things at first like `WARN`, `ERROR` etc

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Cassandra to 3.11.2 solved this issue, but I don't have any insight into why unfortunately.  It simply stopped happening.